# Swift - enlarge custom table row image by selecting row

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView with rows that contain an image - I want to make the selected row image bigger I have researched and have this code, however, it is returning my default cell image, defined in the custom cell and NOT the image in the selected table row.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! myCell
 let items = self.itemsarray[indexPath.row]
    self.imageTapped(image: cell.itemsImageView.image!)
}

  func imageTapped(image:UIImage) {
    let newImageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    newImageView.image = image
    newImageView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    newImageView.backgroundColor = .black
    newImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    newImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ItemViewController.dismissFullscreenImage(_:)))
    newImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)


    self.view.addSubview(newImageView)
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
}
```

This is the problem line `self.imageTapped(image: cell.itemsImageView.image!)` Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! myCell
```

with

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at:indexPath) as! myCell
```

as `tableView.dequeueReusableCell` is supposed to return another cell for usage not your clicked cell , you should only use it inside `cellForRowAt`

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are trying to create new cell when you call this:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! myCell
```

That means you always get your default image or nil if you haven't set it yet. You have to get reference for cell which has already been created and which has diffrent image in its image view. So instead you have to call this:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at:indexPath) as! myCell
```

*Btw. your class name myCell should start with capital letter*